# HIVE Docker container to use with existing Hadoop instances

Tags: docker, hadoop, hive, docker-compose

I have 2 working containers for Hadoop HDFS (I have built a `Dockerfile` for them starting from the one [here](https://github.com/Segence/docker-hadoop)) and need to add a HIVE instance to the set.

I cannot find a good working image to use (it would be nice to have version 2.3.4).

Is there anything you suggest, easy to add, that I could use?

Thank you!

**Edit**:

Here is a try I did:

```
hive-server:
        container_name:   hive-server
        image:            bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
        depends_on:
            - hadoop-namenode
        env_file:
              - ./hive_build/hadoop-hive.env
        environment:
            HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL: "jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
            SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "hive-metastore:9083"
        ports:
            - "10000:10000"
        restart:          unless-stopped

hive-metastore:
    container_name:   hive-metastore
    image:            bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    depends_on:
        - hive-server
        - hive-metastore-postgresql
    env_file:
        - ./hive_build/hadoop-hive.env
    command:          /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    environment:
        SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "hadoop-namenode:50070 hadoop-datanode1:50075 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432"
    ports:
        - "9083:9083"
    restart:          unless-stopped

hive-metastore-postgresql:
    container_name:   hive-metastore-postgresql
    image:            bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0
    ports:
        - "5433:5432"
    restart:          unless-stopped
```

but when I enter it and try to connect I get an error:

```
docker exec -it hive-server bash

/opt/hive/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

error:

```
19/05/03 09:13:46 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0)
```

Comment: I would suggest using PrestoDB rather than Hive... The Hive metastore can just use a Mysql or Postgres container

Comment: @cricket_007, unfortunately I have to use HIVE ):, anyway I have updated my answer

Comment: Does the `bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore` have both a metastore and a HiveServer? I assume either than image needs changed or you need to override a `command` so that it starts one or the other... I don't have experience running these in Docker, so not able to help much